How to define a product of two symplectic vector spaces
Given two symplectic vector spaces $(V_1,\omega_1)$ and $(V_2,\omega_2)$, I want do define their product $V_1 \times V_2$ which would be endowed with symplectic structure $\omega$.
Is $\omega((u_1,u_2),(v_1,v_2)) = (-1)\omega_1(u_1,v_1)\omega(u_2,v_2)$ for $u_1,v_1 \in V_1$ and $u_2,v_2 \in V_2$ the most natural way one could do this or there are some other reasonable symplectic structures on $V_1 \times V_2$?
UPD: It is not a linear 2-form, it would be if we consider $\omega ((u_1,u_2),(v_1,v_2)) = \omega_1(u_1,v_1) + \omega(u_2,v_2)$
Another possible question:
Will my definition lead to the construction of direct product in the category of symplectic vector spaces and linear maps $f: (V_1,\omega_1) \to (V_2,\omega_2)$ such that $f^{\ast}\omega_2 = \omega_1$?

If I understood correctly - you are asking whether the product of two symplectic forms should be defined as their multiplication? This does not give a linear two-form (try multiplying one of the vectors by two, the result will be four times bigger). The usual definition is the sum of the two symplectic forms. (in some contexts the difference is used).

@ReiHenigman Thank you, now I see that your (usual) definiton does make sense
